# cv::mat to UIImage conversion not recovering exact image

Tags: iphone, opencv, uiimage, mat

I am using this function to convert cv::mat to UIImage.

```
-(UIImage *)UIImageFromCVMat:(cv::Mat)cvMat
{
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:cvMat.data length:cvMat.elemSize()*cvMat.total()];
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace;

    if (cvMat.elemSize() == 1) {
        colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
    } else {
        colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    }

    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((CFDataRef)data);

    // Creating CGImage from cv::Mat
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(cvMat.cols,                                 //width
                                        cvMat.rows,                                 //height
                                        8,                                          //bits per component
                                        8 * cvMat.elemSize(),                       //bits per pixel
                                        cvMat.step[0],                            //bytesPerRow
                                        colorSpace,                                 //colorspace
                                        kCGImageAlphaNone|kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault,// bitmap info
                                        provider,                                   //CGDataProviderRef
                                        NULL,                                       //decode
                                        false,                                      //should interpolate
                                        kCGRenderingIntentDefault                   //intent
                                        );


    // Getting UIImage from CGImage
    UIImage *finalImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    return finalImage;
}
```

The recover image color doesn't match with original image. I getting cv:Mat from CvVideoCamera delegate

```
- (void)processImage:(Mat&)image
{
    UIImage* img = [self UIImageFromCVMat:image]
}
```

what is wrong with this code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is probably related to default color space order of openCV (bgr). I think you should check CGImageCreate constructor for figuring out the root cause.

Comment: Thanks fuatcoskun for perfect answer

Comment: Did you fix this issue? Could you share your code if you did?

Comment: cvtColor(image, image, CV_BGR2RGB);

Answer (score 8):

Here is the my working code

```
- (UIImage *)UIImageFromMat:(cv::Mat)image 
{
    cvtColor(image, image, CV_BGR2RGB);
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:image.data length:image.elemSize()*image.total()];

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace;

    if (image.elemSize() == 1) {
        colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray();
    } else {
        colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    }

    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((CFDataRef)data);//CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((__bridge CFDataRef)data);

    // Creating CGImage from cv::Mat
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(image.cols,                                 //width
                                        image.rows,                                 //height
                                        8,                                          //bits per component
                                        8 * image.elemSize(),                       //bits per pixel
                                        image.step.p[0],                            //bytesPerRow
                                        colorSpace,                                 //colorspace
                                        kCGImageAlphaNone|kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault,// bitmap info
                                        provider,                                   //CGDataProviderRef
                                        NULL,                                       //decode
                                        false,                                      //should interpolate
                                        kCGRenderingIntentDefault                   //intent
                                        );


    // Getting UIImage from CGImage
    UIImage *finalImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    //[self.imgView setImage:finalImage];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    return finalImage;

}
```

Comment: cool! Worked for me. Any chance to have different cold code (CV_BGR2RGB) for other device (iPad, iPhone 6Plus) ? Is there any way to detect color space of device programatically ?